# UIAlertController from extension

Tags: ios, swift

I have code to **test** the **insertion** of **only digits**.

How can I make an alert with a message if I insert letters?

[image]

**String+onlyNumbers.swift**

```
extension String {
    func onlyNumbers() ->String{
        do{
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "([//.,\\d])*", options:[.dotMatchesLineSeparators])
            var result : String = ""

            for resultMatch in regex.matches(in: self, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions.init(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, NSString(string: self).length)) {
                result += NSString(string: self).substring(with: resultMatch.range)
            }
            return result
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        return ""
    }
}
```

**ViewControler.swift**

```
let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Past",comment: ""), style: .default, handler: {
    (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    self.displayResultLabel.text = UIPasteboard.general.string?.onlyNumbers()
    print("Pasted")
})
```

**"""""**

```
let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Past",comment: ""), style: .default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        if UIPasteboard.general.string?.onlyNumbers() == "" {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Calc Pro", message: UIPasteboard.general.string, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alertController, animated: false, completion: nil)
        } else {
            self.displayResultLabel.text = UIPasteboard.general.string
        }
        print("Pasted")
    })
```

Comment: What are you actually asking? You don't now how to show an alert? Or you don't know, how to assign dynamic text as the alert's text?

Comment: @DávidPásztor first and second

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show all of your relevant `UIAlertController` code and clear explain what your question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an alert by instantiating a `UIAlertController`. You can use the output of your `onlyNumbers` function as the message of the alert controller.

Then you need to add `UIAlertAction`(s) to it and finally call `self.present` to display the alert controller from a `UIViewController` subclass.

```
if UIPasteboard.general.string?.onlyNumbers() == "" {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Calc Pro", message: UIPasteboard.general.string?, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alertController, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: You can add the `saveAction `  to the alert controller as well just as shown in my answer for the `Ok` action. The code in my answer creates the exact same alertcontroller as in your questions since you asked how to create an alert like that.

Comment: I need to make an alert with a message if I insert letters

Comment: Check my updated answer. Call this piece of code after you have tried to insert letters.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? How do you call this code?

Comment: Look """ in question

Comment: So what do you mean by doesn't work? Do you receive an error? Or the alert just doesn't appear?

Comment: I'm sorry I can add text "cannot be pasted" after ... (title: "Calc Pro", message: UIPasteboard.general.string ...

Comment: Just use String interpolation: `message: "\(UIPasteboard.general.string ?? "") cannot be pasted"`.